# how to count image pixel

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv

i want to know how to apply this "The horizontal position, counting pixels from the left edge of the image, of the center of the smallest rectangular box that can be drawn with all "on" pixels inside the box." 
Note that the box==image

using opencv code

any help

Comment: I think your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you want to deliver.

Comment: @MizukiKai  i want to know how to how to count the x pixels in image
all point in image have P(x,y) how to count x pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly or not but this is my suggestion to count pixels in an image.

The Mat image I used below is grayscale, if you want to  count pixels on a 3channel RGB image, you need to split its channels and handle them seperately.

```
Mat image= imread( "C:\\1.jpg" );// load your image by giving the path here.
Mat grayscale_image;

cvtColor(image,grayscale_image,CV_RGB2GRAY);/* this converts "image" to 
"grayscale_image" which is a one channel image.*/

//Now you can play with its pixels

 int sumPixels=0;

                     for(int i=0; i<image.rows; i++)
                     {
                         for(int j=0;j<image.cols;j++)

                                sumPixels+=image.at<uchar>(i,j);                            

                     }

/* value of a pixel on a gray scale image(if it is a 8 bit image) varies between 
   0 and 255. "sumPixels" variable will contain the total pixel values of image.*/
```

Comment: Thanks for replay,but how can i define mat image , please more explain to know how .

Comment: I edited the answer as you asked

Comment: Thanks Thanks,but i need to know the pixels coordinates  x and y and make summation to x-coordinates and y-coordinates

Comment: which pixels ? you should understand it from the code, it is already in the code above. i and j variables are for coordinate. Maybe you should start from scratch the OpenCV.

Comment: i try your code and get error is Mat undefined ,what is a class type or headers lib to define Mat and cvtColor

Comment: try adding  **using namespace cv;** to the top of your program after includes

Answer (score 0):

This code tries to find white pixel at each row by summing all the white pixel at each column.

```
    int sum_of_x = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        { 
            if(data[i*step + j]==255)
                sum_of_x = sum_of_x + 1;
        }
        cout<<"Row No #"<<i<<", White Pixel at each ROW = "<<sum_of_x<<endl;
    }
```

Cheers.